# How to draw a Dendogram for complete link method in agglomerative hierarchical clustering algorithm

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

After calculating the distances each element have with each other, what should be the next step to create the Dendogram for Complete Link Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine we have 6 data items i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6 and their distances should depict like in the following diagram.

```
      i1     i2     i3     i4     i5     i6
---------------------------------------------
i1     -
i2   d1.2     -
i3   d1.3   d2.3     -
i4   d1.4   d2.4   d3.4     -
i5   d1.5   d2.5   d3.5   d4.5     -
i6   d1.6   d2.6   d3.6   d5.6   d5.6    -
```

Complete link means the furthest neighbor. So that should be express in the Dendogram. The last value of the vertical axis in the dendogram would be the longest distance.

First take the pair which have the smallest distance. If there are more than one pair with the same distance value, just start by the pair which you first came across. [Would prefer to go row by row and get the first pair which came across] Then merge those two pairs in the dendogram with that distance value in the vertical axis. [When drawing the dendogram it's better not to label the axis values at the start. Label them on going through the process so you can avoid having overlapping lines.]

Then go for the next pair. If this new pair affect the pairs already in the dendogram, check whether those distances from pairs that can be build up, have higher values than the new pair distance. If so, ignore the new pair and go for next. If it doesn't you can merge them in dendogram with that distance value in the vertical axis.

For example:

- lowest distances is d2.3.
- d2.3 < d3.4 < .............. < d2.4

So i2 and i3 is merged in the dendogram at the value in the vertical axis d2.3.
Next pair (i3,i4) affect i3 already in the dendogram which can build another pair (i2,i4) if merged. As its distance d2.4 is much higher than the d3.4, this new pair (i3,i4) can be ignored without merging now.

Likewise you can draw the dendogram depicting furthest neighbor at its furthest distance value.